# How can I find problem in javascript code

Tags: javascript, debugging

Yesterday, I was playing around with my JavaScript and suddenly I have strange Bugs in my Code, that I could not solve.

My Website loads a svg-element:

```
<div id="content">
<svg id="drawing"
     title="Layouteditor"
     viewBox="0 0 600 500"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     version="2.0"
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
     onload="makeDraggable(evt)">
</svg>
</div>
```

With some `console-loggign`, I can see, that `makeDraggable` is run once. Directly after `document` is loaded (`document.ready`) I get the following message:

> 0: 'makeDraggable' is not defined

I definitely know that this function worked without any issues before. I tried to empty everything so only document Ready has this line:

```
console.log("documentReady");
```

And also `makeDraggable` has one line

```
console.log("makeDraggable");
```

This is the Output:

> makeDraggable 8 (780,9) documentReady 8 (709,9) 0: 'makeDraggable' is
>   not defined

Of Course I have a bunch of other functions in my site but how could I find out, where the second call Comes from and why it is running into an error?

Comment: Sounds like `makeDraggable` is not global

Comment: Make sure that the name of the function or the name you are using the reference hasn't changed. If the problem is not there, check where the function is being declared, is it being added to the global scope? If not check which objects owns it, and call use `owner_object.makeDraggable` instead. If the function is not a public property of any global object, then just add it using `object.makeDraggable = makeDraggable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my fault.
I added a link to a Stylesheet in my MVC-Site.
In this Stylesheet I had a fault, that I didn't see because Styling worked as expected.
Seems that SVG has some Problems with Styling.
I tried to style a text

```
.CDC400 {
font: 10px sans-serif;
fill: black;
stroke-width: 0;
}
```

This class is attached to a SVG Text.
If I try to fill: red; everything works, with black it doesn't???
Also Hex-values don't work. WTF?

...Update, HEX-Values work after second refresh of the site...